# Extension with a receive value

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I'm learning about extension in swift and I want to create a extension for `String` like the command `.hasPrefix()`, in that command we send a String, for test it I try this code:

```
extension String{

    var teste:(String) { return "\(self) - \($1)" }

}

texto.teste("other String")
```

But not working, all I want to do is create a extension that we can send other values like `.hasPrefix` (that send a string inside) `.hasSufix` (send a string too), How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var teste: String { ... }` is a *computed property*, and computed
properties cannot take parameters.

You'll want to define an extension *method*:

```
extension String {

    func teste(arg : String) -> String {
        return "\(self) - \(arg)"
    }
}

println("foo".teste("bar"))
// foo - bar
```